# Ao clicar no arquivo.sql ele vai para Mysql Workbench

Tags: spring-boot

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que clico no arquivo selecionado que é um arquivo SQL ele abre o Mysql Workbench, era para abrir um arquivo no spring tools.

Isso deve ser alguma configuração da IDE, alguém teria uma sugestão para me ajudar?

Comment: Está usando o eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo arquivo no eclipse é vinculado a um editor de texto (algum highlight em especifico). Pode configurar isso atráves do menu: `Window>preferences`. No threeview a esquerda vá em `General>Editors>File Association`.

Nessa tela primeiro adicione a extensão `*.sql` no botão `add` no canto superior esquerdo.

Depois com extensão selecionada adicione o editor de texto desejado, text editor para textos simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]